# 2 weeks ago from meta query meta value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, date-time

This is my meta query within my posts query.

```
'meta_query' => array(

                array(
                    'key' => 'rw_membership_ends',
                    'value' => ???????
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                ),

 )
```

I want to select posts that have rw_membership_ends (in datetime format) older than the current value of the rw_membership_ends filed minus 14 days.

What should I put in 'value' ?

I need something like

```
'meta_query' => array(

                array(
                    'key' => 'rw_membership_ends',
                    'value' => 'rw_membership_ends_value' - 14 days
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                ),

 )
```

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried? A quick search [pulls up this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651263/subtract-1-day-with-php) which should be able to send you on your wayyyyyy!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee read my comment again. I need to subtract days from a value in database, not from a known string.

Comment: It might be too far in now but if you could save that data (membership_ends - 14d) as additional meta when you save your post that would be optimal. Otherwise I *believe* you'll need to create some custom SQL to figure out this sort of thing.

Comment: Exactly, I need some shortcut or custom SQL, because if I have to make subqueries based on the date, it would be too cumbersome.